# Changing format of date

Tags: perl, date-formatting

How can I change the format of dates `12/23/02` to `23/12/2002` or `03/35/55` to `35/03/2055`?

I can read the dates from text file but I can't change their format:

`15/06/17` ====> `06/15/2017`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the example using [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-Format-Strptime-1.54/lib/DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm):

**UPDATE:**

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
my $str = '12/23/02';
my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new( pattern => '%m/%d/%y');
my $dt = $parser->parse_datetime( $str );
print $dt->strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

output:

```
23/12/2002
```

Comment: Did you know that DateTime objects have a strftime() method? `print $dt->strftime('%d/%m/%Y')` seems simpler.

Comment: I guess you could even eliminate $dt completely - `print $parser->parse_datetime( $str )->strftime('%d/%m/%Y')` :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the Perl Module *Time::Piece* should work

```
use Time::Piece 'strptime';
my %date = strptime('%d/%m/%y', '15/06/17');
```

The date hash contains then the parsed date elements, $date{d}, $date{m}, and $date{y} which you can use to reformat the date.

Comment: Why not just `my $date = strptime('%d/%m/%y', '15/06/17')->strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`?